# TensorFlow MNIST DataSet

Tags: python, tensorflow

I started to learn TensorFlow by reading a book which started by classifying MNIST digits.

[Link to the code](https://github.com/Hezi-Resheff/Oreilly-Learning-TensorFlow/blob/master/04__convolutional_neural_networks/mnist_cnn.py)

```
MINIBATCH_SIZE = 50
STEPS = 5000

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(STEPS):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(MINIBATCH_SIZE)

    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1],
                                                       keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step {}, training accuracy {}".format(i, train_accuracy))

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

X = mnist.test.images.reshape(10, 1000, 784)
Y = mnist.test.labels.reshape(10, 1000, 10)
test_accuracy = np.mean(
    [sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X[i], y_: Y[i], keep_prob: 1.0}) for i in range(10)])

print("test accuracy: {}".format(test_accuracy))
```

This is the block of code which executes the session. My question is - the for loop iterates STEPS times and batch is the mini batch of size 50.

Shouldn't we iterate STEPS times over the whole training set? This code only trains 50 images in an epoch.

What am I missing here? How does the next_batch() method work

Answer (score 0):

## Question

How many iterations should be do over a training set?

## Answer

The answer usually is *"as many as it takes"*.  Okay, I admit that doesn't really help at first so let's get some jargon out of the way.  There is a term **Epoch** that means *one whole pass over the data*.  That's kinda that minimum IMHO.  If you don't go over the whole data set at least once then what's the point?  The MNIST data set has about 50,000 training images (60,000 if you don't split our validation).  So your tensorflow graph in order to accomplish **1 Epoch** would have to process 50,000 images.  If your batch size is 50, then that's 1,000 batches.  In your above code your batch size is 50 and you do 5,000 batches, in effect you are doing **5 Epochs** worth of processing, or 5 passes over the whole data set.

## Question

How does the next_batch() method work?

## Answer

**next_batch** returns the specified number of images and labels from the training set.  It wraps around so that when you are at the end of your data set it starts back at the beginning.  It makes it easy to just get more data instead of having to code the looping and wrapping and slicing of the data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch size

Tensorflow is using **gradient descent**: at each step in your `for` loop, you evaluate the error between your predictions and the actual digits to find a gradient for adjusting the weights in your neural net.

You could indeed go through your entire test set each time, but you'd be processing the whole set just to nudge the weights, then going through it all again just to nudge the weights again, and so on. This would work, but be slow for large data sets.

At the other extreme, you could just pick one example in the loop. This is called **stochastic gradient descent**. Because you only process one example at each step it's very fast, but it's not guaranteed to converge and progress will be rather "jerky".

The code here is doing **batch gradient descent** which is a halfway house between these two approaches. By processing 50 examples each time the weights are adjusted, you get faster training than full gradient descent and more stability that stochastic gradient descent.

### `next_batch`

The `next_batch` method just gets the next *N* records from the test set. By default, as here, the records are shuffled. You can call it as many times as you like; once the records are exhausted it will start again from another shuffled set. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py) if you're interested.

### Experimentation

There are 60,000 training images in the MNIST dataset. You could run this code three times, setting `MINIBATCH_SIZE` to 1, 50 and 60000 respectively to see for yourself how it performs in each case.